# How can I pass a variable to an interpreted file?

Tags: php

So I have a case were I need to interpret a PHP file and then put it in a variable as a string.

I have this some what common helper function to do this:

```
function ob ($path) {
    ob_start();
    include($path);
    $string = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $string;    
}
```

Just give it the path and it will give you the string after it has been interpreted.  Works great.

However I also need to send it a variable.  I tried just appending a GET request string to the path, but it appeared not to work.  The function prototype would look like this:

```
// how would I implement this?
function ob ($path, $variable_to_send) {  
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Why don't use the same code? `$variable_to_send` should be accessible from inside the `$path` script too.

Comment: The gist of the question is, I need to send the variable to a different file, i.e. the on being interpreted.

Comment: the file being interpreted is a php script, right? Inside the php script you could refer to `$variable_to_send` and use that variable. By the way this approach is "unusual".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a global variable.

Set it in one file like this:

`$GLOBALS['arg'] = 'test';`

Access it in another file similarly:

`$arg_passed = $GLOBALS['arg'];`

If you wanted to architect this a bit more use the registry pattern.

Note this assumes that this is the same HTTP request.  If you need persistence across HTTP requests use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let the external script is *external.php*:

```
<?php
echo $argument;
?>
```

and the caller scrip is *caller.php* (on the same folder of *external.php*):

```
<?php

function ob ($path, $argument) {
  ob_start();
  include($path);
  $string = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $string;
}

$out = ob("external.php","Ciao");
echo "$out Cade";
?>
```

The result will be:

```
Ciao Cade
```